# Why doesn't jQuery FullCalendar ask to refetch events in week view when crossing over a month?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using [jQuery Fullcalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) which works great in month view.  I am now playing around with week view.  The issue is that as I move back and forth from week to week, it only seems to refetch events when the start of the week is in a new month.  So if there is a week view that is 1/2 of one month and 1/2 of a new month (for example, the last week in July 2012 where it starts on July 29th but ends on August 4th), then it won't request to refetch events. It only refetches events when I click forward one more time and I am on the week of (Aug 5 - Aug 11).

The issue is I am only loading events for 1 particular month on the server (so I am not loading the first few days of the next month). See my code below where I am passing in the month and year so my server knows which data to query.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/EventCalendar/GetCalEvents/',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    month: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth() + 1,
    year: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getUTCFullYear(),
  },
  success: function (data) {
    callback(data.Events);
  }
});
```

Is this by design and I should really be returning events for the first week of the next month as well, or is this a bug? Why isn't full calendar triggering an event request?

Comment: Good catch! Have you tried with a different weekMode? Like `weekMode: 'liquid'` or `weekMode: 'variable'`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView')`?

This will return a [view object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/) which contains a start and end time. Rather than pass a single month and year, you can pass these values, and return all of the events that are happening during the time span the view is showing.

Even better, you can use full calendar's ability to pull [directly from a json feed](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/). The start and end values are automatically passed as url params, and events are updated when the view changes (such as when moving from week to week, month to month, day to day or from any of the main views).

EDIT: After re-reading this, you may want to try setting [lazyFetching](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/) to false as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your default view is set to **Month**. When the calendar is loaded it loads the events of the whole month. Now when you switch to the **week view** it doesn't load the events because it already has the events of the whole month. FullCalendar intelligently fetches events.
If you set the default view to week or day like this:

```
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
```

You'll see it will load event for each week separately.
I hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining your own `$.ajax(...)` functionality and setting your own range (by parsing `.fullCalendar('getDate')`) use the built-in data sources. You will then have the *visible* calendar range as input to your ajax server side event fetches.

Set the source when initializing `.fullCalendar(...)`. See the documentation on [setting EventSource `$.ajax(...)` options to fetch JSON calendar event data](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // Put your other fullCalendar options here too
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/EventCalendar/GetCalEvents/',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Logging any error that occured fetching the events
                if(console && console.error){ console.error(arguments); }

                alert("Couldn't fetch events, check the javascript console error log.");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The request to `/EventCalendar/GetCalEvents/` will contain two [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 1970):

- [`start`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/startParam/): start of the first visible day (inclusive)
- [`end`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/endParam/): end of the last visible day (exclusive)
- [`_`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#caching): An optional non-static number used as an [ajax cache busting technique](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache+busting+ajax). Just ignore this.

Example request to your server

```
/EventCalendar/GetCalEvents/?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646
```

Just parse the date values, and return any calendar events that overlap any part of the `start`-`end` range.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not wrong in the data pass to the back-end..Data is passed,,this is what i did...i am new to Fullcalendar...this is what worked for me....

```
 eventSources:
       [

           // your event source
               {

                   url: '/ajax-load-holidays',// use the `url` property
                   type: 'POST',
                   datatype: "JSON",
                   data : function()
                   { // a function that returns an object
                       var date =  new Date($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
                       month_integer = date.getMonth();
                       year_integer = date.getFullYear();
                          return {
                              month: month_integer,
                              year: year_integer
                          }
                   },

                   error: function() {
                       alert('there was an error while fetching eventsin hol!');
                   },
                   color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                   textColor: 'blue' // a non-ajax option

               },


        ],
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        // lets test if the event has a property called holiday.
        // If so and it matches '1', change the background of the correct day

        if (event.holiday == '1') {
            var dateString1 = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

            $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString1 + ']')
                .css('background-color', '#FAA732','.fc-time','disable');
        }

    }
```

//this is my controller...i did this in laravel(MVC-repository)

```
public function LoadHoliday(Request $request)
{



    $this->year = $request['year'];
    $month = $request['month'];


        $month++;
        $this->month=$month;
```

$Rowdata1 = ($this->holidayFixed->getValueMonth("monthOfTheYear",$this-month));
$Rowdata2 = $this->holidayMovable->getValueMonth("monthID",$this->month);

```
    $x=0;
    $data1[] = 0;
    $data2[] = 0;
    if($Rowdata1==null && $Rowdata2==null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {


       foreach($Rowdata1 as $value){

            $mon = $value->monthOfTheYear;
            $day = $value->dayOfTheMonth;



            $dateD =  $this->year. '-' . $mon . '-' . $day;


            $data1[$x] = [
                'title' => $value->description,
                'start' => $dateD,
                'holiday' => '1'

            ];
           $x++;

        }

        foreach($Rowdata2 as $value){
            $year = ($value->yearID);
            $mon = $value->monthID;
            $day = ($value->dateID);

            $dateD = $year . '-' . $mon . '-' . $day;



            $data2[$x] = [
                'title' => $value->description,
                'start' => $dateD,
                'holiday' => '1'

            ];
            $x++;

        }
        if($data1==['0'] && $data2==['0'])
        {

          return 0;
        }
        elseif($data1==['0'])
        {

            return $data2;
        }
        elseif($data2==['0'])
        {

            return $data1;
        }
        else
        {
            unset($data2['0']);
            $data3 = array_merge($data1, $data2);

            return $data3;

        }


    }


}
```